# Simulating real camera data

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosbag, data, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

Is there a way I can simulate camera data similarly to how rosbag works? I tried rosbag but was missing tf data so that didn't work.

is it as simple as adding another topic to record? looking through the available topics I don't see anything that looks like what I need.

In essence what I want to do is, record the data stream of my cameras to pass to my perception pipeline so I can start working on making the robot move to a pick location. I'd like to work at my desk if possible and not at the robot since there isn't much room for my laptop there.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324131/simulating-real-camera-data/) by [pathare](https://answers.ros.org/users/40445/pathare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-05-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-05-28**:\

> but was missing tf data so that didn't work

Did you record the tf topic in the bag file?

**Comment by [pathare](https://answers.ros.org/users/40445/pathare/) on 2019-05-28**:
Yes, the error that I'm getting in RVIZ is:
"Transform [sender=unknown_publisher]
for frame [camera1_color_optical_frame]: Frame [camera1_color_optical_frame] does not exist."

does this mean something else maybe?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-05-28**:
Have you tried recording every topic and playing that back to if that works?

**Comment by [pathare](https://answers.ros.org/users/40445/pathare/) on 2019-05-28**:
I have not tried that, let me give that a try real quick and get back to you

**Comment by [pathare](https://answers.ros.org/users/40445/pathare/) on 2019-05-28**:
When I subscribe to all on the rosbag with a -a it crashes my software and it wont run. I went back and rerecorded the cameras and the tf and increased the buffer so it stopped filling up and that still didnt work either.

**Comment by [mch](https://answers.ros.org/users/31598/mch/) on 2019-06-07**:
This message means you don't have TF (http://wiki.ros.org/tf) between those cameras published. TF between 2 cameras most likely is the static one. I think you need to record both /tf and /tf_static. Also do **rostopic echo /tf_static** and check that TF between those cameras is there in the output.

**Comment by [pathare](https://answers.ros.org/users/40445/pathare/) on 2019-06-21**:
Sorry it took so long to reply, your suggestion was correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer was suggested by mch,

> This message means you don't have TF
> (http://wiki.ros.org/tf) between those
> cameras published. TF between 2
> cameras most likely is the static one.
> I think you need to record both /tf
> and /tf_static. Also do rostopic echo
> /tf_static and check that TF between
> those cameras is there in the output.

I needed to also record tf_static.

---

Originally posted by [pathare](https://answers.ros.org/users/40445/pathare/) with karma: 28 on 2019-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1